# Как написать собственную bash-команду для linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

Есть самописная библиотека python3, подскажите, как написать собственную bash-команду, которая будет вызывать функцию с аргументами из терминала?
На данный момент функцию библиотеки можно вызвать только из шела питона(python3).

Comment: Напишите `#!/usr/bin/env python3` в первой строке python-файла, добавьте бит выполнения python-файлу (`chmod +x ./скрипт.py`) и запускайте его путём прописывания в bash пути к нему. Аргументы, которые прописываются в bash, будут доступны внутри python-скрипта в списке `sys.argv`

Comment: Спасибо! только вопрос: если библиотека планируется распространяться как пакет дистрибуции - [link](https://github.com/h0llapuppy/diff_branches) , то все описанные вами шаги точно также нужно выполнить? насколько я понимаю, путь к нему невозможно будет указать(поправьте, если я ошибаюсь)

Comment: Чтобы файл можно было запускать просто по имени без указания пути, он (или симлинк на него) должен лежать в одном из каталогов, прописанных в [переменной окружения PATH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F))

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, но возник еще вопрос) после установки пакета появляется питоновский архив(?): /usr/local/lib/python3/site-packages/get_diff_branches-1.0-py3.9.egg . Каким образом возможно создать симлинк к файлу, лежащему в этом архиве?

Comment: Какого пакета (в каком он формате) и как устанавливается?

Comment: С помощью команды python3 setup.py install (sudo). архив лежит по [ссылка на репо](https://github.com/h0llapuppy/diff_branches) - папка dist

Comment: Тогда следует использовать штатную фичу [scripts или console_scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html), чтобы setup.py сам создал скрипт где надо (обычно в `~/.local/bin` или `/usr/local/bin`)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Благодаря вашим ответам сумел сделать все необходимое. Могу ли я как-то повесить на ваши ответы - лучший ответ?) Недавно зарегистрировался на этой платформе, еще не зная всех тонкостей